# how I can know which version of mod security that I had on the server? and how I can update it?

Tags: mod-security

I'm using cpanel (11.25 Stable 46156) with mod security installed. How can I know the version of mod security that installed in the server?

How  can I update mod security manually or make it update automatically ?

Comment: To find the version on Ubuntu you can run following with root user permission, apt-cache show libapache2-mod-security2

Answer (score 7):

Another way to find it out is by simply restarting your Apache server and look in the logs for info:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart

$ grep -i modsecurity /var/log/apache2/error.log

[Sun Mar 08 19:14:02.000210 2015] [:notice] [pid 1912] ModSecurity for Apache/2.7.7 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Sun Mar 08 19:14:02.000278 2015] [:notice] [pid 1912] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.5.1-dev"; loaded version="1.5.1-dev"
[Sun Mar 08 19:14:02.000290 2015] [:notice] [pid 1912] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.31 "; loaded version="8.31 2012-07-06"
[Sun Mar 08 19:14:02.000300 2015] [:notice] [pid 1912] ModSecurity: LUA compiled version="Lua 5.1"
[Sun Mar 08 19:14:02.000308 2015] [:notice] [pid 1912] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.1"
```

Answer (score 2):

[cPanel Apache 1.3 uses Mod security 1.x and Apache 2.x uses mod security 2.x](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/EasyapacheModsecurity)

To know which apache you have running type on the shell command line: `httpd -V`

To know the exact version of mod_security installed, find the file `mod_security.c` open it with any editor such as nano, vi or the one you prefer and look for the line: `#define MODULE_RELEASE`

If you have apache 2.x you can simple compile it again with the latest tarball file to upgrade it to the latest version, a step-by-step is available at:

http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/2.5.12/html-multipage/installation.html

Comment: sorry but i could not find mod_security.c file , by the way i'm using rhel 5

Comment: in your httpd.conf what is the loadmodule line you have for mod_security ?